# Overwrite a javascript function in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

What must i do to overwrite a javascript function?

I bound the `plotAreaClick` event from the Kendo UI chart to the javascript `onPlotAreaClick` function. My goal is to use/display the `placeholder` variable in the `onPlotAreaClick`.

*These are not working (jsfiddle line:45):*
`onPlotAreaClick(Placeholder)`
`onPlotAreaClick(this, Placeholder)`

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/rule_34/gpurwayr/1/

```
var seriesData = [{
    productname: "Product One",
    volume: 65.50
}];

function onPlotAreaClick(e) {
    alert(kendo.format("Plot area click :: {0} : {1:N0}", e.category, e.value));
}   

$(document).ready(function() {
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
function createChart(ChartType, Placeholder, MaxValue) {

    $("#" + Placeholder).kendoChart({   
        theme: "metro",
        title: {
            font: "12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
            color: "#29952D",
            text: "Name: " + Placeholder
        },
        dataSource: {
            data: seriesData
        },          
        seriesDefaults: {
            labels: {
                template: "#=kendo.format('{0:n2}', (Math.abs(value)))# ltr",
                position: "outsideEnd",
                visible: true,
                background: "transparent"
            }
        },                              
        series: [{
            type: ChartType, 
            field: "volume",
            categoryField: "productname",
        }],     
        valueAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            max: MaxValue
        }],
        chartArea: {
            width: 125,
            height: 175                 
        },
        plotAreaClick: onPlotAreaClick, /* HERE */
    }) // kendoChart
} // function
// -------------------------------------------------------------------          
createChart("column", "example_1", 200);    
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
}); // $(document).ready(function()
```

Comment: The linked jsfiddle works as expected and displays a message box when I click the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholder is the ID of the chart DIV right? In the click event, `e.sender` is the chart object, `e.sender.element` is the DIV, so the id can be had by `e.sender.element.prop("id")`.

```
function onPlotAreaClick(e) {
    alert(e.sender.element.prop("id"));
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gpurwayr/2/)**

UPDATE: From OP's comment

Change plotAreaClick to an anonymous function and then pass placeholder to the onPlotAreaClick function:

```
        plotAreaClick: function(e) {
            onPlotAreaClick(e, Placeholder);
        },

function onPlotAreaClick(e, Placeholder) {
    alert(Placeholder);
}
```

> **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gpurwayr/3/)**

Comment: I think your idea is the same like this:

 plotAreaClick: function(e){ 
  console.log(kendo.format("Plot area click :: {0} : {1:N0}", e.category, e.value));
  onPlotAreaClick(Placeholder)
 },


And now the function could output the Placeholder data:

 function onPlotAreaClick(value) {
  console.log(value);
 }

But my question was: How could i call the function and tranfer the "e" value together with the Placeholder variable.

Comment: @Bettelbursche, see updated answer and fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gpurwayr/3/)